# Value of variable being reinitialized

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a class Reporter. Inside the constructor I have initialized a counter. The counter is incremented inside a function addStepLog. After sometime when the same counter variable is called inside the afterEachScenarioStep function the value is being initialized to 0. Please note that @AfterStep is a cucumber annotation (using cucumber-java 4.2.5). Below is my code.

```
public class Reporter {

      private final Object lockObject = new Object();
      private int counter;
      private List<String> stepLog;

      public Reporter() {
        stepLog = new ArrayList<>();
        counter = 0;
      }

      public void addStepLog(String message) {
        synchronized (lockObject) {
          this.counter++;
          stepLog.add(message);
        }
        System.out.println("Counter Value in addStep " + this.counter);
      }

     @AfterStep
      public void afterEachScenarioStep(Scenario scenario) {
        System.out.println("Value of Counter " + this.counter); // The value of counter is 0 here.
        if (stepLog.size() > 0) {
          System.out.println(counter++);
          synchronized (lockObject) {
            stepLog.forEach(scenario::write);
          }
        }
        scenario.embed(screenshotArray, "image/png");
      }
```

The size of the arryList is 0 and the counter is also reinitialized to 0. I am pretty sure cucumber is doing something funny.

I have created only one instance of Reporter from the Login class. The reporter is not being used anywhere else.

```
public class Login {

  private JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
  Reporter reporter = new Reporter();

  public void launchBrowser(String device) {
    reporter.addStepLog("Launched the Browser.");
    reporter.addStepLog("Launched the Browser.");
    driver(device).launchUrl(jsonParser.getValue(device, "url"));
  }

  public void clickForgotPassword(String device) {
    reporter.addStepLog("This is a dummy Step");
    reporter.addStepLog("This is a dummy Step2");
    reporter.addStepLog("This is a dummy Step3");
    reporter.addStepLog("This is a dummy Step4");
    driver(device).click("account.forgetPassword");
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the other code where this is being used?

Comment: i bet the second reporter is not the same as the first one...and so on

Comment: @aran It's the same instance of Reporter.

Comment: @brso05 Did not understand your question...

Comment: Can anyone tell me the reason for -2 downvotes?

Comment: @Vineeth brso05 ask for the the code where you instantiate `Reporter`

Comment: Is there anywhere you reset those vars, besides the constructor? Are you 100% sure that the instance of the reporter is the same, always? If it is, we're missing code. If there's not such resetting code, you are creating new Reporter instances each time.

Comment: In the addStepLog function incrementing is in the synchronized block, but in the afterEachScenarioStep function it is not. This may be the reason, but we need code with initialization and usage of Reporter.

Comment: @aran Added the code where I'm instantiating the reporter class. It's the same instance of the Reporter.

Comment: I'm no downvoter, neither intent to. But those votes are trying to tell you there's much more information needed here in order to give you an answer.

Comment: The cucumber `AfterStep` annotation: comment it out maybe. It reeks of special flows. I also would have guessed that Login was created more than once, serialization were used, several threads started, unit test resets, or such.

Comment: @JoopEggen Just read your comment, was trying stuff on the same lines... I think cucumber might messing stuff around.

Comment: Cucumber will re-initialize all step and hook classes before running each scenario. Reporter class is a hook class so the list and int variables will be empty and 0 respectively.  U can make them static but in a multi threaded parallel running environment fingers crossed. U could look at creating a custom plugin by implementing the EventListener interface. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/formatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grasshopper's comment is the correct answer: `cucumber-jvm` destroys and re-creates the "world" (which includes all steps and glue objects) for each feature. Therefore you are getting a new instance of `Reporter` for each feature.

There are some workarounds listed here: https://automationpanda.com/2017/03/03/cucumber-jvm-global-hook-workarounds/

Static variables are the simplest workaround.

Comment: I did take Grasshopper's suggestion and implemented a custom interface. Even though static is a easier approach, I just cannot come to terms with it using Static, it seems wrong...